# Nginx catch-all config file

Tags: nginx

### ***Gave up on this, I'll leave it up in case someone has a solution for someone else in the future. Deleted vbox so I cant test them anymore. I, instead, will use apache2.***

I would like to configure my nginx server on my dev machine to work for all paths matching a file name.

**For example a project has the following branches so I check them out:**

/var/www/version1.1/html

/var/www/version1.2/html

/var/www/version2.1/html

**Here is the important part of the config file:**

```
root /var/www;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index home.php index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ version(.+)/html/\.php$  {
        alias $1/html;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index home.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

**EDIT2**
also tried:

```
location / {
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index home.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

**The problem:**

If I load the `location ~ \.php$` only the server returns php files correctly. However, it wont load css and js includes in the right path, it tries to load them from var/www instead of the base directory say /var/www/version1.1/html so obviously that's not workable since they'll never find the files.

**EDIT:**

I would like

`localhost/version1.1/html/register` to load `/var/www/version1.1/html/register.php`

`localhost/version1.1/html/css/main.css` to load `/var/www/version1.1/html/css/main.css`

`localhost/version1.2/html/register` to load `/var/www/version1.2/html/register.php`

`localhost/version1.2/html/css/main.css` to load `/var/www/version1.2/html/css/main.css`

I also want to be able to checkout say version1.6 and have it work like the others without having to go and edit the config file every time.

Comment: Please provide examples of the URLs and corresponding filesystem locations you want to use. Like: `http://www.example.com/xyz/something.html` should load `/var/www/xyz/something.html`. I cannot see this information from the question now, so it is difficult to guess an answer.

Comment: Edited to clarify. Also given what I tried to look up it seems nginx just can't work like this, so it'll simplify the nginx vs apache questions I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

You should make it work with this location block:

```
location / {
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php =404;
}
```

Then you need to use the standard PHP `location ~ \.php$` block from normal nginx configuration in addition to this.

`try_files` first tries to serve the physical file with `$uri` and `$uri/` variables. If no such file is found, then it tries to load a filename with a `.php` added to end, and finally it returns 404 if none such file is found.

You also need to make sure you have a proper `root` statement. In your case it should be:

```
root /var/www;
```

It can be either on `server` level or `location /` level.

Comment: It loads the pages already, this still does, with no CSS or JS for the same reasons mentioned above. The actual default config doesn't (and cannot) work because installer for nginx doesn't check what version of php is running and doesn't set itself up accordingly. So we fix that by putting in the localhost IP on port 9000 for the fpm. This is a localhost dev environment. Edited original post to show attempted code.

Comment: The only thing you need to change for another PHP version is the endpoint for PHP-FPM so that it matches the one PHP uses. You must not modify the matching criteria for the PHP block nor add any other directives.

Comment: I added one further requirement to my answer.

Comment: Still nothing, lets not waste any more time on this, I'll stick with apache.